# mining (& searching in) github projects

Tags: github, data-mining

Is there any way to find every github project which:

- is GPL licensed
- has over one million lines of C++ code

I am imagining that the [Github API](https://developer.github.com/v3/) was designed to automate such requests, but I am not sure at all.

In other words, is the GitHub API related to searching within all the existing github projects?

Another request might be to find every project in C or C++ having a *single* line containing `fork ();` with only spaces before and after that. This would approximate (ignoring those few who would code `pid_p p =` on one line and `fork();` on the next) the quest for badly written programs which do not keep the result of `fork` (as they [should](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28680655/841108))

PS. Google codesearch was in the past somehow useful for such things. It has vanished.

Comment: There's also http://code.openhub.net/

Comment: Would the [github tag on WebApps.SE](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bgithub%5D+api+is%3Aq) more closely be able to answer the question?